# How do I do the parkour (green hoop) mission near the bridge?

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

I am trying to do [Brick 35 listed here](http://au.ign.com/wikis/lego-marvel-super-heroes/Gold_Bricks_27-49) - green hoops appear with maybe five seconds between them.

Unfortunately, when I jump off the second building and slide down the rope, I move through the ring without the game acknowledging it so it times out instead of activating the next ring.

Is this a bug (I'm on Xbox 360)?  Is there a known fix?  Or am I supposed to be approaching the run some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleared this gold brick just fine last night, by following the route as marked by the trail of studs.

I did not note any issues with clearing the rings on the ziplines.  I did miss a zipline jump at one point and recovered by flying (miraculously - the flight controls are bonkers!).

It's possible it's a glitch, and I've seen a few things like this in my playtime.  Usually I have to dashboard out (Xbox button, then Y) and then come back into the game afterwards.

Comment: I realised by checking the stud trail *carefully* that I was skipping a hoop.  (Goddamned terrible camera angles!)  Funnily enough, that was causing the following hoop to not register!

Comment: @Margaret, yep, that'll do it.  There's a little blue arrow that also points to the next hoop on these checkpoint races.  These arrows are generally very hard to use, but they can at least be a good sanity check if you're not sure you're on the right path.